# Conformal vector fields in $m$-dimensional Euclidean manifold

Tags: homework-and-exercises, differential-geometry, symmetry, vector-fields

A vector field $X=X^\mu\partial_\mu\in\mathfrak{X}(M)$, where $M$ is a (pseudo-)riemannian manifold with a generic metric tensor $g_{\mu\nu}$, is a *conformal Killing vector field* if the *conformal Killing equation* \eqref{CKE} is satisfied:

$$
\tag{1}\label{CKE}\mathcal{L}_Xg_{\mu\nu}=X^\lambda\partial_\lambda g_{\mu\nu}+g_{\mu\lambda}\partial_\nu X^\lambda+g_{\lambda\nu}\partial_\mu X^\lambda=\psi g_{\mu\nu}
$$

where $\psi\in\mathcal{F}(M)$ is a smooth function with the following relation with the metric tensor

$$
\psi(x)=\frac{1}{m}(g^{\mu\nu}X^\lambda\partial_\lambda g_{\mu\nu}+2\partial_\lambda X^\lambda)
$$
(that you can get doing the trace of \eqref{CKE}, $m=\dim M$).

Now I'm trying to get Killing vectors and conformal Killing vectors of the $m$-dimensional Euclidean manifold, so we have a constant metric tensor $g_{\mu\nu}=\delta_{\mu\nu}=\operatorname{diag}(1,\dots\,1)$ and the connection coefficients are $\Gamma=0$, so we have  $\partial_\mu\partial_\nu=\partial_\nu\partial_\mu$ in this particular example.

Equation \eqref{CKE} in this case is

$$
\partial_\mu X_\nu+\partial_\nu X_\mu=\frac{2}{m}\delta_{\mu\nu}\partial_\lambda X^\lambda
$$

and, doing some manipulations, you can get an equation where there is a combination of the third derivative of $X^\mu$ equal to zero. From this you can infer that a (conformal) Killing vector is at most quadratic in $x$. Then four possibilities are presented

1. $X^\mu=a^\mu$, $m$ traslations (KV)
2. $X^\mu=\lambda x^\mu$, 1 dilatation (CKV)
3. $X^\mu=w^\mu_{\ \nu} x^\nu$, $\frac{1}{2}m(m-1)$ rotations (KV)
4. $X^\mu=b^\mu x^2-2x^\mu b_\lambda x^\lambda$, $m$ **special transformations** (CKV)

I'm having a hard time interpreting the latter. I found that $\psi\propto -b_\lambda x^\lambda$, but I don't know how to interpret this conformal symmetry.

Comment: how come you ask this in physics , its pure math

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth, a [special conformal transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_conformal_transformation) $K=I\circ T\circ I$ can e.g. be understood as a composition of the [inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversive_geometry) $I: \vec{x}\mapsto  \vec{x}/|\vec{x}|^2$, a translation $T$, and the inversion $I$.